# heatmap plot with own color for some values in r

Tags: r, colors, scale, heatmap

Here is data:

```
set.seed(123)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(5000, 0.5, 0.2), 50)
heatmap (mat)
```

[image]

```
mat[mat > 0.05] <- NA
heatmap (mat)

Error in hclustfun(distfun(x)) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 11)
```

By replacing with other values (arbitrary can help) but it can trick the readers as it will pick color from the same scale, which is not true. So I want to put completely different color for those value greater than 0.05.

```
mat[mat > 0.05] <- 0.1
heatmap (mat)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe...

```
library(gplots)
set.seed(123)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(5000, 0.5, 0.2), 50)
heatmap.2(mat, breaks=c(-1,0.02,0.05,1), col=c("yellow", "red", "blue"), 
# aiming for >0.05 is blue
dendrogram="both", trace="none")
```

Basically play around with `col=` and `breaks=`

looks like:

[image]